# Serialize DataTable to GeoJSON object?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2013, json.net, geojson

I've been having trouble converting a datatable into a GeoJSON object.

The datatable looks like this:

```
Name       Status       imageUrl          lat       lon
Joe        Dev          markers/Dev.svg   34.21092  -77.59384
Mary       Dev          markers/Dev.svg   32.49323  -78.43144
```

The GeoJSON should look like this:

```
{
    "type" : "FeatureCollection",
    "features" : [
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "properties" : {
                "Name " : "Joe",
                "Status" : "Dev",
                "imageUrl" : "markers/Dev.svg",
                "lat" : 34.21092,
                "lon" : -77.59384
            },
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -77.59384, 34.21092 ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type" : "Feature",
            "properties" : {
                "Name " : "Mary",
                "Status" : "Dev",
                "imageUrl" : "markers/Dev.svg",
                "lat" : 32.49323,
                "lon" : -78.43144
            },
            "geometry" : {
                "type" : "Point",
                "coordinates" : [ -78.43144, 32.49323 ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I've been searching everywhere, but have yet find a solution. I've been using NewtonSoft for serializing a `DataTable` to a `JSON` object, but GeoJSON is a much more complex format.

The most difficult part is having to include categories within other categories. In any case,  this is what I've tried:

Using `Newtonsoft`, I'm able to convert the datatable to a JSON. Obviously, it's not the solution:

```
string callback = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataTable);
[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(callback);
return new System.IO.MemoryStream(resultBytes);
```

One step forward, this is what I tried to add some geojson properties:

```
var envelope = new
{
    type = "FeatureCollection",
    features = result.Tables[0]
};

string callback = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope);
byte[] resultBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(callback);
```

This returns something closer, but it's still missing the `{"type": "Feature", "properties"` within each array.

And finally, I posted a similar question here, and it was very helpful, but it takes as parameter the actual `json` instead of the `datatable`, which brings a host of other issues, mainly this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557559/cannot-deserialize-the-json-array-e-g-1-2-3-into-type-because-type-requ).

So I decided to just start from scratch and post a question asking how I can take my source (a regular datatable) and convert it into a `GeoJson` object like the one above.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far, any bit of `c# code` to share?

Comment: I didn't post any code thinking users would focus on that instead of the question, but you're right. I'll post what I've tried.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50616994/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-geojson-in-c-sharp

Comment: Yes, I did. It takes a json object as parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map the `dataTable` records into a multi dimensional object structure. I suggest doing so with LinQ.

To iterate on a dataTable, use the `.AsEnumerable()` on the dataTable object.

**Solution :** Create a function that `convert` the `DataTable` into a GeoJSON string.

Make sure to imports the `System.Linq` `namespace` in your `.cs` file

```
public static string DataTableToGeoJSONString(DataTable dataTable)
{

    var envelope = new
    {
        type = "FeatureCollection",
        features = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Select(record => new {
            type = "Feature",
            properties = new
            {
                Name = Convert.ToString(record["Name"]),
                Status = Convert.ToString(record["Status"]),
                imageUrl = Convert.ToString(record["imageUrl"]),
                lat = Convert.ToDecimal(record["lat"]),
                lon = Convert.ToDecimal(record["lon"])

            },
            geometry = new
            {
                type = "Point",
                coordinates = new[] {
                    Convert.ToDecimal(record["lon"]),
                    Convert.ToDecimal(record["lat"])
                }
            }
        }).ToArray()
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(envelope);
}
```

And the just get the JSON string out of it

```
string geoJson = DataTableToGeoJSONString(dataTable);
```

Note that this code sample uses anonymous classes `new {}`. It works but I would recommend to use strongly typed class that you'll have to create.

That should serialize in the expected GeoJSON format.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.